# NextJS API route is caching responses even thought it is set not to cache

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a very strange issue in NextJs API routing. I am using NextJS 13.5.6.

My Project flow is

- User call nextjs api from browser
- That nextjs api will call external api which is to one of my microservices.

Problem Statement

- My nextjs api is caching responses and returing old responses even thought I have changed values in my microservice
- This cache is not on browser level because I changed with different browsers and incongnito mode. If the cache is on client level, calling with new browser should work.
- It is not cached on microservice's external api because this api passed through api gateway and I can see in api gateway logs that responses are up to date

My fixes

- I added `fetch('https://...', { cache: 'no-store' })` to every fetch calls in my app.
- I didn't add any redis or caching mechanism.

My file structure
I used generic api builder which is generic fetch function (not custom, orginal javascript fetch) which is used to call apis. One for nextjs API and one for external api. My file structure is like -

- apiBuilder

  - nextJSApiBuilder.ts
  - remoteApiBuilder.ts
- app

  - api

    - config

      - route.ts
  - page.tsx

I call api/config using nextJSApiBuilder.ts in pages and I use remoteApiBuilder.ts to call external api in config/route.ts.
All of my pages are not SSR because I use `use client`.

I suspect that this is data caching causing this issue

```
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating
```

But I don't know where is the place causing issue.

I also saw suggestion to add route.ts

```
export const revalidate = 0;
```

but I don't think this is the issue because route.ts is from server side why do we need to force to be dynamic?

Please help me on this issue.

nextJSAPIBuilder.ts

```html
const localApiBuilder = async (
  url: string,
  method: string,
  payload: any = undefined
) => {
  const headers = new Headers();
  try {
    const options: RequestInit = {
      method: method,
      headers: headers,
      cache: "no-store",
    };

    if (payload !== undefined) {
      options.body = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }

    const res = await fetch(
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_INTERNAL_API_URL + url,
      options
    );
    const data = await res.json();

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    return data;
  } catch (e: any) {
    throw e;
  }
};

export default localApiBuilder;
```

remoteApiBuilder.ts

```html
import RemoteApiCustomError from "@/model/remoteApiResponse/RemoteApiCustomError";
import RemoteApiErrorType from "@/model/remoteApiResponse/RemoteApiErrorType";
import RemoteApiFailedResponse from "@/model/remoteApiResponse/RemoteApiFailedResponse";
import RemoteApiSuccessResponse from "@/model/remoteApiResponse/RemoteApiSuccessResponse";

const remoteApiBuilder = async <T>(url: string, body: T | undefined) => {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const timoutId = setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), 20000);

  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  headers.append(
    "Apim-Subscription-Key",
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY as string
  );

  const options: RequestInit = {
    method: body ? "post" : "get",
    headers: headers,
    signal: controller.signal,
    cache: "no-store",
  };

  if (body) {
    options.body = typeof body === "string" ? body : JSON.stringify(body);
  }

  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL + url,
      options
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);

    if (!response.ok) {
      const errorResponse = data as RemoteApiFailedResponse;
      console.log("response is not ok");
      console.log(errorResponse);
      throw new RemoteApiCustomError(
        RemoteApiErrorType.API_FAILED_ERROR,
        errorResponse.errorMessage
      );
    }

    const possiblyFailedResponse = data as RemoteApiSuccessResponse;
    if (possiblyFailedResponse.errorCode !== 0) {
      //is failed response
      // const errorResponse: RemoteApiErrorResponse = JSON.parse(
      //   possiblyFailedResponse.response as string
      // ) as RemoteApiErrorResponse;
      throw new RemoteApiCustomError(
        RemoteApiErrorType.NON_ZERO_ERROR,
        possiblyFailedResponse.errorMessage
      );
    }

    console.log(
      "fetch success response",
      possiblyFailedResponse.response,
      url,
      options
    );

    //is success response
    return possiblyFailedResponse.response;
  } catch (error: any) {
    if (error.name === "AbortError") {
      //Timeout error
      throw new RemoteApiCustomError(
        RemoteApiErrorType.TIME_OUT_ERROR,
        "Request timed out"
      );
    } else if (error instanceof RemoteApiCustomError) {
      throw error;
    } else {
      throw new RemoteApiCustomError(
        RemoteApiErrorType.UNKNOWN_ERROR,
        JSON.stringify(error)
      );
    }
  } finally {
    clearTimeout(timoutId);
  }
};

export default remoteApiBuilder;
```

api/config/route.ts

```html
import FNPConfig from "@/model/config/FNPConfig";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import remoteApiBuilder from "@/apiBuilder/remote.api.builder/remote.api.builder";
import translateRemoteApiCustomError from "@/utils/translateRemoteApiCustomError/translateRemoteApiCustomError";
import performRequestBasicCheck from "@/utils/performRequestBasicCheck/performRequestBasicCheck";

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  performRequestBasicCheck(request, request.method, "GET");

  try {
    const response: FNPConfig[] = (await remoteApiBuilder(
      "/RetrieveFNPConfig",
      undefined
    )) as FNPConfig[];

    return NextResponse.json(response ? response[0] : [], { status: 200 });
  } catch (e: any) {
    return translateRemoteApiCustomError(e);
  }
}
```

This function is called from pages.

```html
import { GET } from "@/constants/config";
import FNPConfig from "@/model/config/FNPConfig";
import localApiQueryBuilder from "@/apiBuilder/local.api.builder.ts/local.api.builder";

const localConfigApi = async (): Promise<FNPConfig> => {
  try {
    const response: FNPConfig = (await localApiQueryBuilder(
      "/config",
      GET
    )) as FNPConfig;
    return response ? response : new FNPConfig();
  } catch (e: any) {
    throw e;
  }
};

export default localConfigApi;
```

Comment: Can you show the internal API route you are calling?

Comment: Hi @YoussoufOumar , I believe you meant my route.js. I edited my orginal post. Thank you.

Comment: This is quite weired, you have `cache: "no-store"` but the cache is still happening. I would also rise an issue on their GitHub repo if I were you.